# MySQL matching two tables with different dates

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I wasnt quite sure what to call the question but here is my problem:

in my system i have something called `titles` each `user` in my system has a `title` as a 1..1 relationship

Now a `title` has many `competences` 1..* and a expected level.

When a `user` is given a title he automaticly inherits all of the `competences` over time the `expected level` and the `users` current `level` is changing.

These changes are logged into two tables:

**For user changes:**

```
Table: user_changed_competence_level
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
competence_id   int(11)
user_id int(11)
old_level   int(11)
new_level   int(11)
timestamp   datetime
```

**For title changes**

```
Table: title_competence_change_expected_level
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
title_id    int(11)
competence_id   int(11)
old_level   int(11)
new_level   int(11)
timestamp   datetime
```

Now a change in one table does not equal a change in the other. Which means that the `timestamp` for these two tables does not always match.

Now i wish to find the changes made on both table and how they compare meaning i want to see on for instance `2014-05-05` what both the `title_competence_change_expected_level.new_level` and `user_changed_competence_level.new_level` was

However im unsure on how to get such a resultset seeing as the `timestamps` may not match meaning one of the values if i search for `WHERE timestamp = '2014-05-05'` will be null seeing as there is not column that match.

My question is how can i create such a resultset / view that matches this criteria?

to explain furthur if one of the values should be null i want to find the closest date where there is a value

Comment: 1) you want to see all changes in whole DAY? (for example 2014-05-05)  2) you want to see changes by ONE user or ALL?

Comment: 3) i believe difference between timestamps in two tables is less then 1 seconds? 4) can you give your tables structure and some data in Mysql format? (create table .... ; insert into .... ;)

Comment: @M0rtiis i want to see the changes of the data over a period of time like from 2014-05-05 to 2014-10-05